# How to design data driven test using Selenium IDE with excel or XML file

Tags: automation, automated-tests, selenium-ide

My client wants me to convert script as data driven i.e. accept inputs from XML or MS excel to execute script for regression testing. Can anybody help me here please.

Comment: go through the following link , you will get everything http://unmesh.me/2012/12/04/data-driven-testing-with-selenium-ide/

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer CSV files, which can parsed in JavaScript included in user-extensions.js. With an own defined command (in user-extensions.js too) I would expose/store the parsed CSV data as an object array to a variable and then using the [FlowControl](http://wiki.openqa.org/download/attachments/379/goto_sel_ide.js) commands to iterate over this. Tricky but should work :-)